# invalid assignment left-hand side (railo.transformer.bytecode.op.OpString)

Tags: javascript, facebook, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Can't figure this out, I looked to see if the Facebook JS had any += for concatanation, but I am not seeing anything that is ringing a bell that could be causing this.

```
                <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
                  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

The code is being added after the facebook SDK, so that wouldnt be the issue. Any help would be awesome!

-G

Answer (score 0):

Well, Figured this one out, some reason I totally forgot ColdFusion has to have the "#" escaped, so the JS that was embedded in the page should be always be "##."

-G

Comment: Why do you have this block of code inside a `cfoutput`? (That is the only way that is the issue)

Comment: I have business logic baked into the view, not ideal, but would rather have shared views than have several views with redudent code.

Comment: But, there is no CF code in that code snippet, it does not need to be wrapped in `cfoutput`

Comment: For my circumstance, it has to be. Thank you.

Comment: You have no CF code in that snippet. There is no reason why it needs to be wrapped in a `cfoutput`. You may think it needs to be, but based on what you have provided, it does not.